# Modified Google pushtotalk.py crashes on missing attribute 'DeviceRequestHandler'

Tags: grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I am running on a Raspberry Pi 3b+ with latest Raspbian.  I have created a Python 2.7 virtual environment to test a few things.  I installed the Google Assistant Api using the following instructions:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample
-except the audio, I am using the Respeaker 4-mic hat as I already had that working fine.

When I run the sample code for pushtotalk.py it works fine except CTRL-C no longer functions (have to close the terminal window to kill it).

I made a few minor (or I thought minor) changes and when I run the code I get a strange error.

My version of the code:

```
# Original pushtotalk.py file Copyright (C) 2017 Google Inc.
# modified by @captstephan for T3 project
#
# my imports for the mechanical functions, motor drivers, etc.
from Raspi_PWM_Servo_Driver import PWM
from voice_engine.source import Source
from voice_engine.channel_picker import ChannelPicker
from voice_engine.kws import KWS
from voice_engine.doa_respeaker_4mic_array import DOA
from pixels import pixels

# imports from the original Google pushtotalk.py file
import concurrent.futures
import json
import logging
import os
import os.path
import pathlib2 as pathlib
import sys
import time
import uuid

import click
import grpc
import google.auth.transport.grpc
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.credentials

from google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2 import (
    embedded_assistant_pb2,
    embedded_assistant_pb2_grpc
)
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, retry_if_exception

import assistant_helpers
import audio_helpers
import browser_helpers
import device_helpers

# set up Google Assistant variables (from pushtotalk.py)
ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT = 'embeddedassistant.googleapis.com'
END_OF_UTTERANCE = embedded_assistant_pb2.AssistResponse.END_OF_UTTERANCE
DIALOG_FOLLOW_ON = embedded_assistant_pb2.DialogStateOut.DIALOG_FOLLOW_ON
CLOSE_MICROPHONE = embedded_assistant_pb2.DialogStateOut.CLOSE_MICROPHONE
PLAYING = embedded_assistant_pb2.ScreenOutConfig.PLAYING
DEFAULT_GRPC_DEADLINE = 60 * 3 + 5

# set up items for motor hats
# Initialise the PWM device using the default address
pwm = PWM(0x6F)

# set max and min, servo0=Horiz, servo1=vert
servoMin0 = 155  # Min pulse length out of 4096
servoMid0 = 370
servoMax0 = 585  # Max pulse length out of 4096

servoMin1 = 410  # Min pulse length out of 4096
servoMid1 = 530
servoMax1 = 650  # Max pulse length out of 4096

pwm.setPWMFreq(60)  # Set frequency to 60 Hz


# class assignment from pushtotalk.py file:
class SampleAssistant(object):
    """Sample Assistant that supports conversations and device actions.

    Args:
      device_model_id: identifier of the device model.
      device_id: identifier of the registered device instance.
      conversation_stream(ConversationStream): audio stream
        for recording query and playing back assistant answer.
      channel: authorized gRPC channel for connection to the
        Google Assistant API.
      deadline_sec: gRPC deadline in seconds for Google Assistant API call.
      device_handler: callback for device actions.
    """

    def __init__(self, language_code, device_model_id, device_id,
                 conversation_stream, display,
                 channel, deadline_sec, device_handler):
        self.language_code = language_code
        self.device_model_id = device_model_id
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.conversation_stream = conversation_stream
        self.display = display

        # Opaque blob provided in AssistResponse that,
        # when provided in a follow-up AssistRequest,
        # gives the Assistant a context marker within the current state
        # of the multi-Assist()-RPC "conversation".
        # This value, along with MicrophoneMode, supports a more natural
        # "conversation" with the Assistant.
        self.conversation_state = None
        # Force reset of first conversation.
        self.is_new_conversation = True

        # Create Google Assistant API gRPC client.
        self.assistant = embedded_assistant_pb2_grpc.EmbeddedAssistantStub(
            channel
        )
        self.deadline = deadline_sec

        self.device_handler = device_handler

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, etype, e, traceback):
        if e:
            return False
        self.conversation_stream.close()

    def is_grpc_error_unavailable(e):
        is_grpc_error = isinstance(e, grpc.RpcError)
        if is_grpc_error and (e.code() == grpc.StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE):
            logging.error('grpc unavailable error: %s', e)
            return True
        return False

    @retry(reraise=True, stop=stop_after_attempt(3),
           retry=retry_if_exception(is_grpc_error_unavailable))
    def assist(self):
        """Send a voice request to the Assistant and playback the response.

        Returns: True if conversation should continue.
        """
        continue_conversation = False
        device_actions_futures = []

        self.conversation_stream.start_recording()
        logging.info('Recording audio request.')

        def iter_log_assist_requests():
            for c in self.gen_assist_requests():
                assistant_helpers.log_assist_request_without_audio(c)
                yield c
            logging.debug('Reached end of AssistRequest iteration.')

        # This generator yields AssistResponse proto messages
        # received from the gRPC Google Assistant API.
        for resp in self.assistant.Assist(iter_log_assist_requests(),
                                          self.deadline):
            assistant_helpers.log_assist_response_without_audio(resp)
            if resp.event_type == END_OF_UTTERANCE:
                logging.info('End of audio request detected.')
                logging.info('Stopping recording.')
                self.conversation_stream.stop_recording()
            if resp.speech_results:
                logging.info('Transcript of user request: "%s".',
                             ' '.join(r.transcript
                                      for r in resp.speech_results))
            if len(resp.audio_out.audio_data) > 0:
                if not self.conversation_stream.playing:
                    self.conversation_stream.stop_recording()
                    self.conversation_stream.start_playback()
                    logging.info('Playing assistant response.')
                self.conversation_stream.write(resp.audio_out.audio_data)
            if resp.dialog_state_out.conversation_state:
                conversation_state = resp.dialog_state_out.conversation_state
                logging.debug('Updating conversation state.')
                self.conversation_state = conversation_state
            if resp.dialog_state_out.volume_percentage != 0:
                volume_percentage = resp.dialog_state_out.volume_percentage
                logging.info('Setting volume to %s%%', volume_percentage)
                self.conversation_stream.volume_percentage = volume_percentage
            if resp.dialog_state_out.microphone_mode == DIALOG_FOLLOW_ON:
                continue_conversation = True
                logging.info('Expecting follow-on query from user.')
            elif resp.dialog_state_out.microphone_mode == CLOSE_MICROPHONE:
                continue_conversation = False
            if resp.device_action.device_request_json:
                device_request = json.loads(
                    resp.device_action.device_request_json
                )
                fs = self.device_handler(device_request)
                if fs:
                    device_actions_futures.extend(fs)
            if self.display and resp.screen_out.data:
                system_browser = browser_helpers.system_browser
                system_browser.display(resp.screen_out.data)

        if len(device_actions_futures):
            logging.info('Waiting for device executions to complete.')
            concurrent.futures.wait(device_actions_futures)

        logging.info('Finished playing assistant response.')
        self.conversation_stream.stop_playback()
        return continue_conversation

    def gen_assist_requests(self):
        """Yields: AssistRequest messages to send to the API."""

        config = embedded_assistant_pb2.AssistConfig(
            audio_in_config=embedded_assistant_pb2.AudioInConfig(
                encoding='LINEAR16',
                sample_rate_hertz=self.conversation_stream.sample_rate,
            ),
            audio_out_config=embedded_assistant_pb2.AudioOutConfig(
                encoding='LINEAR16',
                sample_rate_hertz=self.conversation_stream.sample_rate,
                volume_percentage=self.conversation_stream.volume_percentage,
            ),
            dialog_state_in=embedded_assistant_pb2.DialogStateIn(
                language_code=self.language_code,
                conversation_state=self.conversation_state,
                is_new_conversation=self.is_new_conversation,
            ),
            device_config=embedded_assistant_pb2.DeviceConfig(
                device_id=self.device_id,
                device_model_id=self.device_model_id,
            )
        )
        if self.display:
            config.screen_out_config.screen_mode = PLAYING
        # Continue current conversation with later requests.
        self.is_new_conversation = False
        # The first AssistRequest must contain the AssistConfig
        # and no audio data.
        yield embedded_assistant_pb2.AssistRequest(config=config)
        for data in self.conversation_stream:
            # Subsequent requests need audio data, but not config.
            yield embedded_assistant_pb2.AssistRequest(audio_in=data)


@click.command()
@click.option('--api-endpoint', default=ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT,
              metavar='<api endpoint>', show_default=True,
              help='Address of Google Assistant API service.')
@click.option('--credentials',
              metavar='<credentials>', show_default=True,
              default=os.path.join(click.get_app_dir('google-oauthlib-tool'),
                                   'credentials.json'),
              help='Path to read OAuth2 credentials.')
@click.option('--project-id',
              metavar='<project id>',
              help=('Google Developer Project ID used for registration '
                    'if --device-id is not specified'))
@click.option('--device-model-id',
              metavar='<device model id>',
              help=(('Unique device model identifier, '
                     'if not specifed, it is read from --device-config')))
@click.option('--device-id',
              metavar='<device id>',
              help=(('Unique registered device instance identifier, '
                     'if not specified, it is read from --device-config, '
                     'if no device_config found: a new device is registered '
                     'using a unique id and a new device config is saved')))
@click.option('--device-config', show_default=True,
              metavar='<device config>',
              default=os.path.join(
                  click.get_app_dir('googlesamples-assistant'),
                  'device_config.json'),
              help='Path to save and restore the device configuration')
@click.option('--lang', show_default=True,
              metavar='<language code>',
              default='en-US',
              help='Language code of the Assistant')
@click.option('--display', is_flag=True, default=False,
              help='Enable visual display of Assistant responses in HTML.')
@click.option('--verbose', '-v', is_flag=True, default=False,
              help='Verbose logging.')
@click.option('--input-audio-file', '-i',
              metavar='<input file>',
              help='Path to input audio file. '
              'If missing, uses audio capture')
@click.option('--output-audio-file', '-o',
              metavar='<output file>',
              help='Path to output audio file. '
              'If missing, uses audio playback')
@click.option('--audio-sample-rate',
              default=audio_helpers.DEFAULT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
              metavar='<audio sample rate>', show_default=True,
              help='Audio sample rate in hertz.')
@click.option('--audio-sample-width',
              default=audio_helpers.DEFAULT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_WIDTH,
              metavar='<audio sample width>', show_default=True,
              help='Audio sample width in bytes.')
@click.option('--audio-iter-size',
              default=audio_helpers.DEFAULT_AUDIO_ITER_SIZE,
              metavar='<audio iter size>', show_default=True,
              help='Size of each read during audio stream iteration in bytes.')
@click.option('--audio-block-size',
              default=audio_helpers.DEFAULT_AUDIO_DEVICE_BLOCK_SIZE,
              metavar='<audio block size>', show_default=True,
              help=('Block size in bytes for each audio device '
                    'read and write operation.'))
@click.option('--audio-flush-size',
              default=audio_helpers.DEFAULT_AUDIO_DEVICE_FLUSH_SIZE,
              metavar='<audio flush size>', show_default=True,
              help=('Size of silence data in bytes written '
                    'during flush operation'))
@click.option('--grpc-deadline', default=DEFAULT_GRPC_DEADLINE,
              metavar='<grpc deadline>', show_default=True,
              help='gRPC deadline in seconds')
@click.option('--once', default=False, is_flag=True,
              help='Force termination after a single conversation.')

def main(api_endpoint, credentials, project_id,
         device_model_id, device_id, device_config,
         lang, display, verbose,
         input_audio_file, output_audio_file,
         audio_sample_rate, audio_sample_width,
         audio_iter_size, audio_block_size, audio_flush_size,
         grpc_deadline, once, *args, **kwargs):

# Inserted the following code to set up the snowboy keyword activation using "Hey T3"
    src = Source(rate=16000, channels=4, frames_size=320)
    ch1 = ChannelPicker(channels=4, pick=1)
    kws = KWS()
    doa = DOA(rate=16000)

    src.link(ch1)
    ch1.link(kws)
    src.link(doa)
    pixels.listen()
    pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 370)
    pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 640)

# When snowboy detects the custom keyword, set the camera position to near direction of voice
    def on_detected(keyword):
        position = doa.get_direction()
        pixels.wakeup(position)
        print('detected {} at direction {}'.format(keyword, position))
        if position >= 30 and position <= 180:
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 175)
            pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 500)
        elif position > 180 and position <= 330:
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 560)
            pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 500)
        elif position > 330 or position < 30:
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 370)
            pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 6200)
        else:
            pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 370)
            pwm.setPWM(1, 0, 640)

    # end of stuff I inserted

# Setup logging.
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.INFO)

    # Load OAuth 2.0 credentials.
    try:
        with open(credentials, 'r') as f:
            credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=None,
                                                                **json.load(f))
            http_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
            credentials.refresh(http_request)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error loading credentials: %s', e)
        logging.error('Run google-oauthlib-tool to initialize '
                      'new OAuth 2.0 credentials.')
        sys.exit(-1)

    # Create an authorized gRPC channel.
    grpc_channel = google.auth.transport.grpc.secure_authorized_channel(
        credentials, http_request, api_endpoint)
    logging.info('Connecting to %s', api_endpoint)

    # Configure audio source and sink.
    audio_device = None
    if input_audio_file:
        audio_source = audio_helpers.WaveSource(
            open(input_audio_file, 'rb'),
            sample_rate=audio_sample_rate,
            sample_width=audio_sample_width
        )
    else:
        audio_source = audio_device = (
            audio_device or audio_helpers.SoundDeviceStream(
                sample_rate=audio_sample_rate,
                sample_width=audio_sample_width,
                block_size=audio_block_size,
                flush_size=audio_flush_size
            )
        )
    if output_audio_file:
        audio_sink = audio_helpers.WaveSink(
            open(output_audio_file, 'wb'),
            sample_rate=audio_sample_rate,
            sample_width=audio_sample_width
        )
    else:
        audio_sink = audio_device = (
            audio_device or audio_helpers.SoundDeviceStream(
                sample_rate=audio_sample_rate,
                sample_width=audio_sample_width,
                block_size=audio_block_size,
                flush_size=audio_flush_size
            )
        )
    # Create conversation stream with the given audio source and sink.
    conversation_stream = audio_helpers.ConversationStream(
        source=audio_source,
        sink=audio_sink,
        iter_size=audio_iter_size,
        sample_width=audio_sample_width,
    )

    if not device_id or not device_model_id:
        try:
            with open(device_config) as f:
                device = json.load(f)
                device_id = device['id']
                device_model_id = device['model_id']
                logging.info("Using device model %s and device id %s",
                             device_model_id,
                             device_id)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning('Device config not found: %s' % e)
            logging.info('Registering device')
            if not device_model_id:
                logging.error('Option --device-model-id required '
                              'when registering a device instance.')
                sys.exit(-1)
            if not project_id:
                logging.error('Option --project-id required '
                              'when registering a device instance.')
                sys.exit(-1)
            device_base_url = (
                'https://%s/v1alpha2/projects/%s/devices' % (api_endpoint,
                                                             project_id)
            )
            device_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
            payload = {
                'id': device_id,
                'model_id': device_model_id,
                'client_type': 'SDK_SERVICE'
            }
            session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(
                credentials
            )
            r = session.post(device_base_url, data=json.dumps(payload))
            if r.status_code != 200:
                logging.error('Failed to register device: %s', r.text)
                sys.exit(-1)
            logging.info('Device registered: %s', device_id)
            pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(device_config)).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
            with open(device_config, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(payload, f)

    device_handler = device_helpers.DeviceRequestHandler(device_id)

    @device_handler.command('action.devices.commands.OnOff')
    def onoff(on):
        if on:
            logging.info('Turning device on')
        else:
            logging.info('Turning device off')

    @device_handler.command('com.example.commands.BlinkLight')
    def blink(speed, number):
        logging.info('Blinking device %s times.' % number)
        delay = 1
        if speed == "SLOWLY":
            delay = 2
        elif speed == "QUICKLY":
            delay = 0.5
        for i in range(int(number)):
            logging.info('Device is blinking.')
            time.sleep(delay)

    with SampleAssistant(lang, device_model_id, device_id,
                         conversation_stream, display,
                         grpc_channel, grpc_deadline,
                         device_handler) as assistant:
        # If file arguments are supplied:
        # exit after the first turn of the conversation.
        if input_audio_file or output_audio_file:
            assistant.assist()
            return

# changed the wait for keypress to a wait for keyword using the snowboy module

    # If no file arguments supplied:
    # keep recording voice requests using the microphone
    # and playing back assistant response using the speaker.
    # When the once flag is set, don't wait for a trigger. Otherwise, wait.
        wait_for_user_trigger = not once
        while True:
            if wait_for_user_trigger:
                #click.pause(info='Press Enter to send a new request...
                kws.set_callback(on_detected)
                continue_conversation = assistant.assist()
            # wait for user trigger if there is no follow-up turn in
            # the conversation.
            wait_for_user_trigger = not continue_conversation

            # If we only want one conversation, break.
            if once and (not continue_conversation):
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/pi/T3google.py", line 501, in 
    main()
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in **call**
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/T3google.py", line 425, in main
    device_handler = device_helpers.DeviceRequestHandler(device_id)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DeviceRequestHandler'

I am still new to python, but the sample code from Google works and the code snippet I inserted works stand-alone in another file.

I checked device_helpers.py and DeviceRequestHandler is a class that takes the device_id as input.  It works fine if I call it in pushtotalk.py, but not in the modified code.

Any thoughts anyone?

Thanks in advance,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

I shut down for other reasons, came back and restarted the next day and problem disappeared.  Likely something required a reboot to complete install and I missed it.  That part is working fine now, haven't been able to completely get this to work as expected.